# How can I make this responsive grid layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I thought would be a simple layout turned out to be something I'm not able to accomplish yet.

I need the grid to be responsive and spread from one side to another (it has to be aligned with the text and box above).

[image]

I tried a few options, I commented them out for easier checking:

```css
.big-container {
  padding: 0 20%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  
/*   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 */

/*   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
   */
  
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  
/*   float: left;
  margin-left: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried with `flex` but it doesn't sort nicely the last row, `flex-wrap: wrap` and `float:left` with some margin doesn't align correctly to the left.

Comment: Put the flex stuff back in, and add `.box:last-child {margin-right: auto; }` …?

Comment: If you want a true grid then perhaps take a look at the [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) module designed specifically to support grid-based layouts. If you want to support an unknown number of elements, though, flexbox is what you should stick with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use flexbox and set `justify-content: space-between` then last row will also have the same spacing instead of left align. Instead you can use grid-layout for this.

```css
.big-container {
  padding: 0 20%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```